# DateTimes.toUtc() not working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  var foo = DateTime(2000).toUtc();
  var bar = DateTime.utc(2000);
  
  assert (foo != bar);
}
```

`foo` and `bar` should be equal but they aren't, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong with `toUtc()`. As far as I know `DateTime(2000)` returns the `DateTime` in local time zone and `toUtc()` converts that to UTC, but it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to someone who deleted the answer after posting [this link](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36434#issuecomment-479783388). And thanks to @lrn for answering it:

> DateTime(y, m, d).toUtc() finds the y-m-d time in the local time-zone and then creates a UTC date at the same point in time. So, if I'm in the UTC+2 time zone, and I do DateTime(2019, 04, 02).toUtc(), I start with the local time 2019-04-02T00:00:00+02:00, and then find that the corresponding UTC-time is 2019-04-01T22:00:00Z. That's the same point in time in a different time zone, it answers the question "when the local time is 2019-04-02T00:00:00, what is the time in the UTC time zone".

> When you do DateTime.utc(2019, 04, 02), you get the point in time where the UTC clock showed 2019-04-02T00:00:00Z. If I do toLocal() on that, I'd get the local time 2019-04-02T02:00:00+02:00.